# Logic Correct but Program Crashes

Tags: c++

NOTE: This question is not about reversing a linked list using recursion but about why it crashes. It's more about dynamic memory really.

I'm implementing a linked list and want to have a function in it that recursively reverses it.

```
struct sNode {
    int data;
    sNode* next;
    sNode(int x) {
        data = x;
        next = 0;
    }
    sNode(int x, sNode* n) {
        data = x;
        next = n;
    }
};

class SLL {
    public:
        SLL() : head(0) {}
        sNode* getHead() { return head;}
        void reverseRec(sNode*); // Reverse the list using recursion;
    private:
        sNode* head;
};

void SLL::reverseRec(sNode* node) {
    // Reverse the list using recursion

    if (node == 0) {
        head = node;
        return;
    }
    reverseRec(node->next);
    sNode* temp = node->next;
    temp->next = node;
    node->next = 0;
}

int main() {
    SLL l1;
    l1.addAtEnd(1);
    l1.addAtBeg(2);
    l1.addAtPos(3, 2);
    l1.reverseRec(l1.getHead());
    return 0;
}
```

The program just crashes. Please help me figure out the reason. I think it's got to do with the arguments of the function.

Comment: It crashes saying what? Returning which code? Try running it from command prompt to see the error msg.

Comment: No error. It just crashed on visual studio. Also, R.Sahu fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem.

```
if (node == 0) {
    head = node;
    return;
}
```

You just made the list an empty list. That should be (prefer to use `nullptr` or `NULL` instead of `0` for pointers):

```
if (node == nullptr || node->next == nullptr ) {
    head = node;
    return;
}
```

Comment: My bad. Is my way of passing the head pointer to the function correct though?

Comment: Actually, that was the whole problem. The program works fine now.

Comment: Why do you think `sNode* temp = node->next;` will make temp point to NULL? It doesn't.